# Why is this http request failing in angular 4, but goes through with fiddler?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an http post request through fiddler: using

```
http://localhost:58183/api/Account/Register
```

with a body of

```
{"email":"jbjunk4@outlook.com","password":"Abc1231*","confirmPassword":"Abc1231*"}
```

This executes just fine and the email is registered in the identity database on webapi 2.

However, I have the following code in my authorize.service.ts:

```
 registerUser(localUser: LocalUser) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', this.constants.jsonContentType);
        var creds = JSON.stringify(localUser);
        console.log(creds);
        console.log(this.constants.accountUrl + "Register");

        return this.http.post(this.constants.accountUrl + "Register", creds, { headers: headers })
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

creds = 
{"email":"jbaird9@arsbirder.com","password":"Abc1231*","confirmPassword":"Abc1231*"}

url = http://localhost:58183/api/Account/Register
json-contentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
```

The console shows:
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

home
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
home
Template parse warnings:
The  element is deprecated. Use  instead ("-child ui-shadow':!root}" class="ui-menu-list"
            (click)="listClick($event)">
            [WARNING ->]
                http://localhost:58183/api/Account/Register
authorization.service.ts (47,9)
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

home
ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid character
core.es5.js (1020,1)
   "ERROR"
   {
      [functions]: ,
      **proto**: { },
      description: "Invalid character",
      message: "Invalid character",
      name: "SyntaxError",
      number: -2146827274,
      stack: "SyntaxError: Invalid character
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:788:13)
   at SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37370:13)
   at SafeSubscriber.prototype.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37329:21)
   at Subscriber.prototype._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37260:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37234:13)
   at Subscriber.prototype._error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37260:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.error (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:37234:13)
   at onError (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:108672:17)
   at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2836:13)
   at onInvokeTask (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:90272:21)"
   }

HTTP405: BAD METHOD - The HTTP verb used is not supported.
(XHR)OPTIONS - http://localhost:58183/api/Account/Register

I can't figure this out.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Side note: you can skip JSON.stringify'ing your localUser and pass it directly to your http.post call as an object. Angular will stringify it for you and add the content-type: application/json header for you automatically. As far as debugging your issue, try to look at the request in your developer tools and compare it with your fiddler request maybe?

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with cross origin requests and using localhost.

Comment: I did that... the requests appear to be identical..

Comment: @ppovoski Can you add your comment so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: I could, but there is already a lot of great information on stackoverflow regarding CORS, although nothing specific to Angular4.  Rather than me looking up the specific answer, you already have one.  Add your solution as the correct answer.  That will help others who experience this issue.  I'm okay with a footnote. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the cors attributes to webapi config... and it all started working... var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("", "", "GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS"); config.EnableCors(cors);

Answer (score 0):

This is normally happens if you don't have a `proxy.conf.json` file in your app to allow tour traffic to the server on a different port. Angular has a feature that block traffic from going to a different port unless you force is to. If you haven't got a `proxy.conf.json` file that can you need to do this on your `app root`

> proxy.conf.json

```
 {
    "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:serverPort",
      "secure": false
    }
  }
```

> proxy.config.js

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/api",
      "/auth",
      "/oauth"
    ],
    target: "http://localhost:8080",
    secure: false
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

And update the `package.json`

```
"scripts": {

    "ng": "ng",

    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",

    "build": "ng build",

    "test": "ng test",

    "lint": "ng lint",

    "e2e": "ng e2e"

  },
```

That will allow the anything after `/api` to reach the server

Comment: Are you able to make any call to the server at all? Any other methods?

Comment: I added the cors attributes to webapi config... and it all started working...
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,PUT,POST,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            config.EnableCors(cors);

Comment: @PraveenM I have similar issue, do I need to explicitly add `proxy.conf.json` file under my app folder and update the `package.json` file as mentioned in your post?

Comment: @Juniuz You're going to need the `proxy-config` file, but it's not a must to add it to the `package.json`. If you do add to the `package.json` you won't need to declare the `proxy-config` existence everytime you run `npm start` or `ng serve` as `package.json` will instruct `NPM` of the `proxy-config` file existence.

Comment: Okay, so how I do generate this `proxy-config.json` file? I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition by the way.

Comment: You cannot generate a one, just create a file on the same level as `package.json` and add the config in the file. I do, however, recommend use of the `.js` instead of `.json` as its much neater. I'll add `js` version to the post above.

Comment: @Juniuz As you can see its much neater when adding multiple `endpoints`

Comment: @PraveenM so, I did create `proxy.conf.json` and `proxy.config.js` files and put it same level as `package.json` in my application root.  And, in my `package.json` file, inside the declaration of `scripts` object I have this property `"start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\" ng serve --proxy.config proxy.conf.json",`  But, still I have encountered the "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" when I run the app under my localhost.  Did I miss something?

Comment: @Juniuz You don't need both `json` and `js`. Just need one of them. You need to add `ng serve --proxy-config fiileName`. At the moment you've this `--proxy-config` with `.` instead of `-`.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally happens if you don't have a `proxy.conf.json` file in your app to allow tour traffic to the server on a different port. Angular has a feature that block traffic from going to a different port unless you force is to. If you haven't got a `proxy.conf.json` file that can you need to do this on your `app root`