# Why does http request failed to load resource when using Angular in localhost?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC project which uses ASP.NET WebAPI along with Angular for UI components.  I'm fairly new to Angular so please bear with me.  Below are the config files inside my project.

`package.json` file

```
    {
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "~4.3.4",

    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",

    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "lodash": "^4.16.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~4.0.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",

    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

`systemjs.config.js` file

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        //baseURL: '/',
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': 'app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
                //meta: {
                //    './*.js': {
                //        loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                //    }
                //},
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

`main.ts` file

```
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

// Enable production mode unless running locally
//if (!/localhost/.test(document.location.host)) {
//    enableProdMode();
//}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

`app.routing.ts` file

```
    import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

`app.module.ts` file

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home.component';
import { ChangeService } from './Services/changes.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpModule, routing],
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, ChangeService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`changes.service.ts` file

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ChangeService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }

    get(url: string) {
       return this._http.get(url);
    }
}
```

`app.component.ts` file

```
        import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChangeService } from './Services/changes.service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'moc-landing',
        templateUrl: './app/Components/home.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app/Components/home.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
        maintitle: string;
        statusList: IStatus[];
        showByList: IShowBy[];
        msg: string;

        constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private _changeService: ChangeService) {
            this.maintitle = this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('maintitle');
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            this.LoadStatus();
            this.LoadShowBy();
        }

        LoadStatus(): void {
this._changeService.get('http://localhost:56534/api/MoC/GetStatuses').subscribe(response => { this.statusList = response.json(); });
        }

        LoadShowBy(): void {
 this._changeService.get('http://localhost:56534/api/MoC/GetShows').subscribe(response => { this.showByList = response.json(); });            
        }        
    }
```

Also in my `WebApiConfig.cs`, inside static `Register` method, I also update `routeTemplate` as below.

```
// Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My issue is that, when I run the application from Visual Studio 2017 on http://localhost:5653; I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`

When I looked at the browser's console, this is what I got,
[image]

I test the `http` request directly in my browser's address bar `http://localhost:56534/api/MoC/GetStatuses`, and it gives me the `json` data that I need.  So, there's no problem in WebAPI side.

I found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595500/why-is-this-http-request-failing-in-angular-4-but-goes-through-with-fiddler/44596467?noredirect=1#comment80935141_44596467) and, tried to follow Praveen M answer but it didn't worked for me.

Why did I get (400) bad request?, Did I miss an important configuration in my `app.routing.ts`?

Please, anyone here with a kind heart can spare me a coin?

Comment: _.subscribe(show => { this.showByList = show }, error => this.msg = <any>error);_ why a comma in subscribe ?

Comment: @RahulSingh that doesn't matter anymore.  I have changed that line into this `this._changeService.get('http://localhost:56534/api/MoC/GetShows').subscribe(response => { this.showByList = response.json(); });` but still I got the Http 400 bad request.

Comment: remove the .json from component call you are already doing that in the service

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks for catching that.  I have made some changes on the code, simplified it but still can't get the issue go away.

Comment: That's not a 404 it's a 400 in your screenshot. Make sure your server is configured for CORS

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I have change to `400`, I'm running under my localhost, how do I configure my webAPI to support CORS?

Comment: @Juniuz Google it there are lots of answers

Comment: @Juniuz check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta thanks mate for sharing the link, that's a good jump start for CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, ChangeService]
```

to just:

```
providers: [ChangeService]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after banging my head on the wall. I found the culprit of the issue.  It's a stupid mistake of mine.  The issue isn't on the http request neither related to my localhost.  It was one of the component metadata `templateUrl`. I have mistakenly declare it like this `templateUrl: '<span>Hello</span>'` instead of just `template: '<span>Hello</span>'`

That's why the application throws exception because the component template is in bad form `http://localhost:56534/%0A%20%20%20%20`